# LinearLayout - 3 objects next to each other

Tags: android, android-layout

This will be pretty easy question, but I tried so much answers in other topics and nothing helped :/

What I have and what I want:
[image]

My code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_fullname_upload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_name_mountain_212121"

                android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryBlack" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_counter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="5" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fullname_upload"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLength="250"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:hint="@string/placeholder_chillspot_name"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="sagdkojsgdfjiklnsagdikljsgdafnmkljsagdfmlskagdmgsdaůlksmdgklůsgdamlůksagdsdfztpkmtzrskoůltzersklůodmsljkdmgslkjdgmslkgsedmlgfůdekmgerlaskůmsgadflůsgm,aasgklů,"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

I tried align these object, layout weight and so on, but I am doing some mistake.

Comment: Did you try to put all of them at the same height and put the image and text gravity (not `layout_gravity`) to top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change some of your paddings and margins to see the result but the main point is to change the place of TextView and play with weights for ImageView TextView and  TextInputLayout

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_fullname_upload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                app2:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_swap"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/bb_darkBackgroundColor"

                android:tint="@color/amber_50" />



            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fullname_upload"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:maxLength="250"
                    android:text="sagdkojsgdfjiklnsagdikljsgdafnmkljsagdfmlskagdmgsdaůlksmdgklůsgdamlůksagdsdfztpkmtzrskoůltzersklůodmsljkdmgslkjdgmslkgsedmlgfůdekmgerlaskůmsgadflůsgm,aasgklů,"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_counter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="5" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was doing weight all the time, but I have no idea why, but problem was in paddings, so I mark this as accepted :) Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_fullname_upload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_name_mountain_212121"

                android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryBlack" />    


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fullname_upload"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLength="250"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:hint="@string/placeholder_chillspot_name"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="sagdkojsgdfjiklnsagdikljsgdafnmkljsagdfmlskagdmgsdaůlksmdgklůsgdamlůksagdsdfztpkmtzrskoůltzersklůodmsljkdmgslkjdgmslkgsedmlgfůdekmgerlaskůmsgadflůsgm,aasgklů,"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_counter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="5" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello @Tonteria24 , thanks for reply. In this one my "counter" disappear